# SFMC - Is it possible to pull the entire data structure?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm working with an instance that has what I'll be estimating about 300 DEs, with 80% of the DEs not being used.

I'm curious to hear if anyone had mapped out every single DE, along with it's folder path, and possibly usage (i.e. Automation locations, related automation activities- not even sure if this is possible).

I know there are tools like SFMC Finder & SSJS scripts that can pull INDIVIDUAL DEs, but I'm looking to create a map of every DE that exists in this instance, find it's folder path (this gives some context to the use of the DE), see any connected Automations, and be able to ultimately clean up the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that pulls a batch of 500 DEs.
Put this on a cloudpage, preview, wait a few seconds.

You cannot find "automation usage", but you things like the Folder (CategoryID).
Full list of what is possible can be found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");


var list = [];

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var props = { QueryAllAccounts: true };
var cols = ["Name",
"CustomerKey",
"IsSendable",
"SendableSubscriberField.Name",
"SendableDataExtensionField.Name",
"CategoryID"];
var filter = {
    Property: "IsSendable",
    SimpleOperator: "IN",
    Value: [true,false]
};
var opts = {
    BatchSize: 500
};
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter, opts, props);
 //Write("<br> " + Stringify(data.Results) + "<br>");

for (i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++)
{
    Write("<br> data = Name: " + data.Results[i].Name + 
        ", customerkey: " + data.Results[i].CustomerKey + 
        ", IsSendable: " + data.Results[i].IsSendable + 
        ", CategoryID: " + data.Results[i].CategoryID + 
        ", SendableSubscriberField.Name: " + data.Results[i].SendableSubscriberField.Name +
        ", SendableDataExtensionField.Name: " + data.Results[i].SendableDataExtensionField.Name);
    list.push(data.Results[i].ObjectID);
}
</script>
```

EDIT:
In order to understand automation usage, you could do something similar for queryActivities, with some extra effort. But that would be limited to queries then, and ignore stuff like data extracts, script activities and the likes. For exploration purposes, it might be interesting though.

Answer (score 2):

Although doesn't fulfil your need 100%, hopefully, you will be able to modify it or use along with Jonas' solution. This will list all Data Extensions in your account that are being updated/populated by either Query Activity or an Import Activity in Automation studio, along with the Data Extension's name and External Key.

It uses REST API endpoints for Query Activity and Import Activity to pull all the necessary information and WSProxy to pull Data Extension info.
It then populates the results into a Data Extension, so create a DE to hold the results first:

```
Field: DEName / Text / 250
Field: DEKey / Text / 250
Field: ImportName / Text / 250
Field: QueryName / Text / 250
```

And then you can either run the script on a CloudPage or in Automation Studio.

```js
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
var authEndpoint = 'https://mcxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/', //provide API endpoint
    client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx', //pass Client ID
    client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; //pass Client Secret
var targetDE = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx'; //pass external key of the target DE  
//initiate WSProxy
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
//initiate and clear data extension
var logDE = DataExtension.Init(targetDE);
var props = {
    CustomerKey: targetDE
};
try {
    var data = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props, "ClearData");
} catch (error) {
    Write(Stringify(error));
}
//authenticate to get access token
var payload = {
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret,
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
};
var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
    var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
    var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
    var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url;
}
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
//api call to get all imports  
function getAllImports(accessToken, headerNames, headerValues) {
    var pagesFetched = 0;
    var pagesCount = 1;
    do {
        try {
            var page = pagesFetched + 1;
            var importsUrl = rest_instance_url + 'automation/v1/imports?$page=' + page;
            var getImports = HTTP.Get(importsUrl, headerNames, headerValues);
            if (Platform.Function.ParseJSON(getImports.Status) == 0) {
                var importContent = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(getImports.Content));
                for (var i = 0; i < importContent.items.length; ++i) {
                    var importName = importContent.items[i].name,
                        importDestinationObjectTypeId = importContent.items[i].destinationObjectTypeId,
                        importDestinationObjectId = importContent.items[i].destinationObjectId;
                    if (importDestinationObjectTypeId == 310) {
                        var cols = ["Name", "CustomerKey", "ObjectID"];
                        var filter = {
                            Property: "ObjectID",
                            SimpleOperator: "equals",
                            Value: importDestinationObjectId
                        };
                        var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter);
                        if (data.Results[0].Name) {
                            logDE.Rows.Add({
                                DEName: data.Results[0].Name,
                                DEKey: data.Results[0].CustomerKey,
                                ImportName: importName
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Write("Error");
            }
            pagesFetched++;
        } catch (error) {
            Write("Exception Error: " + Stringify(error));
            pagesFetched = pagesCount + 1;
        }
    } while (pagesFetched < pagesCount);
}
//api call to get all queries 
function getAllQueries(accessToken, headerNames, headerValues) {
    var pagesFetched = 0;
    var pagesCount = 1;
    do {
        try {
            var page = pagesFetched + 1;
            var queriesUrl = rest_instance_url + 'automation/v1/queries?$page=' + page;
            var getQueries = HTTP.Get(queriesUrl, headerNames, headerValues);
            if (Platform.Function.ParseJSON(getQueries.Status) == 0) {
                var queryContent = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(getQueries.Content));
                for (var i = 0; i < queryContent.items.length; ++i) {
                    var queryName = queryContent.items[i].name,
                        targetKey = queryContent.items[i].targetKey,
                        targetName = queryContent.items[i].targetName;
                    logDE.Rows.Add({
                        DEName: targetName,
                        DEKey: targetKey,
                        QueryName: queryName
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Write("Error");
            }
            pagesFetched++;
        } catch (error) {
            Write("Exception Error: " + Stringify(error));
            pagesFetched = pagesCount + 1;
        }
    } while (pagesFetched < pagesCount);
}
if (accessToken != null) {
    getAllImports(accessToken, headerNames, headerValues);
    getAllQueries(accessToken, headerNames, headerValues);
}
```

I am sure above could be improved, but this is all I had time for so far.
Here is the github link in case you need all the instuctions: https://gist.github.com/zuzannamj/b1c50bc6c5704fd630755ed113816422